# htmlagilitypack select <a> tag with specified inner text

Tags: .net, xpath, html-agility-pack

i need to select a tag that contains an innertext i specify.
can anyone help me with the xpath query ie `<a href="#">wake up</a>`. So if i pass wake to the xpath, it should select this a link

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The XPath is simply `//a[starts-with(., 'wake')]`.

Comment: thanks for your response, but i want to check if it contain `wake`, not always equalto or start-with `wake`

Comment: Then use the `contains` function instead e.g. `//a[contains(., 'wake')]`.

Comment: The spec is suitable as documentation: [http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#corelib)

Answer (score 3):

One way (it matches case sensitive):

```
//a[contains(text(), 'wake')]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
//a[.='wake up']
```